# TextBlock in ListViewItem won't wrap

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Currently in my UWP app I have a custom ListViewItem to use as a template for a message received by a service:

```xml
<ListViewItem
x:Class="App.Controls.MessageItem"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
...>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="Picture" />
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Name="Foo" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Name="Bar" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <StackPanel Name="Things" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

When data comes in from the service, I call:

```cs
MessageList.Items.Add(new MessageItem(message));
```

(where the constructor automatically fills in Foo and Bar with the data from the message.)

However, the text in the `MessageItem` does not wrap and just gets cut off, even though TextWrapping on `Bar` is set to `TextWrapping.Wrap` .

Wrapping not working :

[image: WrapingNotWorking]

On another ListView where I am using `MessageItem`, a horizontal scrollbar appears (but not on the `MessageItems` ListView). I'd like to see the wrapping *work*, since it's pretty integral (as messages can get very long).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `StackPanel`'s orientation setting of `Horizontal` is allowing your `TextBlock` to extend infinitely.
I would suggest changing it to

```
ListView Name="MyContainer">
<ListViewItem>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="Picture" />
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Name="Foo" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Name="Bar" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <StackPanel Name="Things" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this is happening is that the width of the `TextBlock` isn't bounded by anything. The easiest way I can think of fixing it is to limit the width of the `StackPanel` that contains the `TextBlock` to the width of the `ListView`.

For example:

```
<ListView Name="MyContainer">
    <ListViewItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Image Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="Picture" />
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding ElementName=MyContainer, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <TextBlock Name="Foo" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBlock Name="Bar" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <StackPanel Name="Things" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Note that I've named the `ListView` and that I've bound the width of the `StackPanel` to it.